# Mesh turns black after baking light

Tags: unreal-4, lightmap

I had to port a project from Unity to Unreal which relied mostly on baked lighting.

When I baked the light (StaticMeshActor set to Static), the 3D model in the map turned black.

Without bake (dynamic lighting):

[image: with dynamic lighting]

After baking the light:

[image: after baked lighthing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the 3D model had not been unwrapped.

You can check this by going into the Static Mesh Editor, double-click on the mesh:

[image]

Take a look at the UV channels for the mesh:

[image]

My model had an empty panel, like below, so I had to unwrap it in Blender.

[image]

It makes sense that Unreal can't determine where to put the light data without the UVs. I'm not sure why this worked in Unity though.

For 3D models that received proper baked light, this view looked like this:

[image]